# Why is js object losing properties in expressJS route

Tags: express

I'm trying to use a "configured object" as a controller in ExpressJS so I can reuse a bunch of code.

Taken from the express configuration:

```
var ctrl = new CRUDServiceAdapter(serviceConfig);
// list
// this works:  ctrl.load()
app.get(serviceURL, ctrl.load);
```

And separately this is part of the object definition:

```
function CRUDServiceAdapter(serviceConfig){
  this.config = serviceConfig;
  this.logger = logModule.logger("service.controller." + serviceConfig.modelName);
};

CRUDServiceAdapter.prototype.load = function(req, res, next){
  this.logger.debug("Creating an object model for " + this.config.modelName);
  res.json({"msg": "Hello World"});
};
```

What I observe is the object property `this.config` is `undefined` when the method is called through an expressJS request. But if I call it directly on the object like in the comments `ctrl.load()` - the config object is populated as expected.

Why is the object losing it's property values when it's executing as a route?

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context is lost:

You are not passing the object `ctrl` as parameter, only a method, so that method is called as any regular function, so `this` is not pointing at ctrl (I guess it is undefined), so try to change your code for:

```
app.get(serviceURL, ctrl.load.bind(ctrl));
```